# Данные в массиве изменяются, как их получать без редактирования кода?

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой постоянного изменения вывода массива, мой массив

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(17) "Example COOL NICE"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Bilal Shaheen"
    ["show_info"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["_multiwidget"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

При активации wp плагина

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
```

деактивирую плагин, вновь активирую

```
array(2) {
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
```

и это происходит постоянно, в том числе и когда редактирую настройки плагина.

Получение данных из массива с помощью кода

```
echo $arr['2']['title']; 
echo $arr['2']['name'];

title = $arr['2']['title'];
name = $arr['2']['name'];

echo $title; 
echo $name;
```

становится не возможным.

**Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in**

Как получать данные из массива так, чтобы не править постоянно код?

```
echo $arr['2']['title']; 
echo $arr['2']['name'];

title = $arr['2']['title'];
name = $arr['2']['name'];

echo $title; 
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ваша задача в том, чтобы получить первый элемент массива вне зависимости от того, какой там числовой индекс, воспользуйтесь функцией `current()`.

```
$cfg = current($arr);
echo $cfg['title'];
```

Comment: teran, спасибо, все четко работает.

Answer (score 1):

Определяем ключ программно:

```
$key = null;
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if($k != "_multiwidget"){
        $key = $k;
    }
}

echo $arr[$key]['title']; 
echo $arr[$key]['name'];

$title = $arr[$key]['title'];
$name = $arr[$key]['name'];

echo $title; 
echo $name;
```

Comment: Максим, спасибо, работает, единственное у вас там пропущен $ в строках title = $arr[$key]['title']; и name = $arr[$key]['name']; У меня работает так: $title = $arr[$key]['title']; и $name = $arr[$key]['name'];

Comment: Добавил символы.